# two datasets within one ssrs report, one sql, other is xml

Tags: web-services, reporting-services

I have a report currently in 2005 SSRS and it has a SQL based dataset which returns numerous fields, one of which is called MATERIAL_ID.  I am trying to create a dynamic XML connection string in a 2nd dataset within that same report, that builds the connection string using that field "MATERIAL_ID".

I get the error "Fields cannot be used in query parameter expressions".  I've tried every route I could really come up with and so far the best success I have is building a text string to display in a column of the report using custom code behind the report of "Public Const WebService = "http:// & Fields!MATERIAL_ID.Value"

That builds the string I would want to use as my connection string within the 2nd dataset to call a webservice.

Basically I want to take results from my first dataset, specifically all of the values it returns for the field "Fields!MATERIAL_ID.Value" and use that list of values in my 2nd dataset using an XML type connection string.

My first dataset is called "Paintcell" which is the SQL query, and the second dataset is called "test" which is currently an XML connection string.

I can hardcode the connection string with a value and it works just fine, but that doesn't help me when I want it to technically call the web service dozens of times.  This particular report tends to return about 200 values for the field MATERIAL_ID.

Thoughts and suggestions are most appreciated.  Thanks in advance!

Comment: You are only going to be able to use one connection string each time you run the report. Currently it looks like you are expecting the connection to change for each record by basing it on a field.

Comment: Thanks for the reply!  It seems like that is how it is designed, which is a shame because if it allowed for the ability to pass values this would open up a whole new world for reporting.

You don't know if there is a way to call a web service without having to set it up as a dataset do you?  Like code based perhaps?